# Firebase Cloud Messaging not working for user segment from firebase console - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can anyone help me? FCM is not working for **user segment** but properly working for single device by given fcm token. From console it shows me "completed" status but not receiving push from my device. I'm using Xcode 9 and Firebase last updated version too.